# managing database to optimize the process

Tags: android, mysql, sql, sqlite

I am developing an android application which will deal with around 100 000 records stored in Mysql DB. I want to know what will be the best approach to optimize the processing of data.

1. One approach is to query data all the time directly from Mysql DB and operate on activity
2. Another approach is to when app starts it fetch all data from DB and store in SqlLite DB remaining query processing is done on SqlLite DB
3. another thing comes to my mind is to fetch the updated records from MySql DB when app starts and store in cache.